# Deep Copying NSMutableArray Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, nsarray, deep-copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [deep copy NSMutableArray in Objective-C ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647260/deep-copy-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

I have two arrays of length 5 with items of a custom class I've built.  I want to copy the first array into the second.  Once copied I want these two arrays to be totally independent (I want to be able to change the first without affecting the second).  I have tried several methods to no avail (when I make a change to one, the other is changed as well).   They are shown below.

1)

```
[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.lifelineList copyItems:YES];
```

My copying protocol for this method is:

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
Lifeline *lifelineCopy = [[Lifeline allocWithZone:zone]init];
lifelineCopy.name = name;
lifelineCopy.phone = phone;
lifelineCopy.email = email;
lifelineCopy.isActive = isActive;
lifelineCopy.contactID = contactID;
return lifelineCopy;
}
```

2)

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self.lifelineList]];
```

My coding protocol for this method is:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
if (self=[super init]){
    self.name = [aDecoder decodeObject];
    self.phone = [aDecoder decodeObject];
    self.email = [aDecoder decodeObject];
    self.contactID = [aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"contactID"];
    self.isActive = [aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"isActive"]>0;
}
return self;
}
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
[aCoder encodeObject:self.name];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.phone];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.email];
[aCoder encodeInteger:self.contactID forKey:@"contactID"];
[aCoder encodeInteger:(NSInteger)self.isActive forKey:@"isActive"];
}
```

3) iterate through the first array, put the instance variables of each element into a temporary variable and then add that variable to the second array.

I am happy to post more code if needed.

Comment: This should help; in the past I've always used the arrayWithArray: call... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749657/nsmutablearray-arraywitharray-vs-initwitharray

Comment: @Krypton - tried it, no go.
@Gilles - I created this question because the methods posted in that thread did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is your custom class properly implementing the `NSCopying` protocol? (I.e. implement `copyWithZone:` to return a completely independent instance.)
2. Is you custom class properly implementing the `NSCoding` protocol to archive and decode all of the relevant instance variables?
3. This won't work unless you actually copy the objects themselves. Simply assigning to a temporary variable does nothing at runtime.

Comment: I have edited the question to show my copy/coding protocols...Perhaps I am doing them wrong?

Comment: Assuming `name`, `email`, and `phone` are `NSString` declared as `copy` properties, I think your copy/coding methods are correct.  There must be something else going on.   How exactly are you determining that the deep copy is not working?

Comment: even though the question was closed I'd still like to thank you for your help.  I found the issue (turns out it was unrelated to the actual copying process).